# Jquery datepicker not working Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker'

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a main page parentFrame.php, which has the jquery plugins are called. This page has three tabs and each tab loads an external page to the parentFrame.php 
So when user clicks Tab A - a.php is opened under Tab A.

In A.php I have to call two datepickers. I have added the date fields and called the simple jquery script

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#StartDate" ).datepicker();
    $( "#EndDate" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
```

The issues is, when i call the A.php directy as a url the date pickers are working. but when the same page is called inside parentFrame.php nothing is happening. I am getting the message `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker'`.

I tried adding the libraries on both files.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: check jquery references

Comment: are you sure `$` is referring jQuery - did you include jQuery UI library

Comment: Be sure that you've included the script after you've included jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused by another library trying to use the `$` variable.

Here is how you can 'workaround' that:

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    $( "#StartDate" ).datepicker();
    $( "#EndDate" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
```

You can also read about jQuery `$.noConflict()` [here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/). This method is helpful if you need to load 2 different versions of jQuery which can also cause behavior and errors like what you're getting.

Comment: Hello thank you all for the response. please find the links here. the link with parentframe and 3 tabs is [here](http://code-weavers.com/jquerytest/showOverallRanking.php). The page called under tab 1 is [here](http://code-weavers.com/jquerytest/showReviews.php) - both links are not displaying any dates now.

Comment: @sathumenon - You are loading _both_ the jQuery (lines 9 & 12) and jQueryUI (lines 13 & 14) libraries twice. Try commenting one of each out so we can get a baseline.

Comment: Thank you. I have kept the pages separate now to avoid further issues.